# Associated Press Style with Monetary Ranges (Your Interpretation)

Tags: punctuation

The AP Stylebook's FAQ accepts "a 30 to 35 percent a year increase" and "a 10-20 percent a year increase in revenues", one with the word "to" in the numerical range, and one with a hyphen. They also permit a hyphen or the word "to" in these: $20,000 to $25,000 and $20,000-$25,000.

Based on this information (and without recasting, please), would you consider the following examples to be correct per AP Style, and in general?

*•It was a $10 million to $15 million a year industry.*

*•The percentages represented a $40,000 to $45,000 a year increase in sales.*

Alternatively, based on AP's supported examples, do you think that hyphens can be used, too?

*•It was a $10 million-$15 million a year industry.*

*•The percentages represented a $40,000-$45,000 a year increase in sales.*

Comment: The examples in the post above certainly look better than the following examples (with all the suspended hyphenation), agreed? The following look horrendous: It was a $10 million- to $15 million-a-year industry.

The percentages represented a $40,000- to $45,000-a-year increase in sales.

Comment: What I meant was that the following examples are not preferred with all the mind-boggling hyphens: a $10 million- to $15 million-a-year industry. The percentages represented a $40,000- to $45,000-a-year increase in sales. (Looking for opinions here.) Instead, the following four examples (without all the hyphenation) would be preferred, yes? •It was a $10 million to $15 million a year industry. •The percentages represented a $40,000 to $45,000 a year increase in sales. •It was a $10 million-$15 million a year industry. •The percentages represented a $40,000-$45,000 a year increase in sales.

Comment: In most style guides, ranges use en dashes, not hyphens. I doubt that AP style is an exception. Also, I'm pretty sure you're putting the dashes in the wrong place. I would normally expect $10–15 million, for example.

Comment: "$10–15 million" looks totally wrong to me. Ten dollars ($10) to 15 million (without a dollar sign before "15")? No way.

Comment: That's not how you read a range like that. The _dollars_ moves to the end of the phrase, so it becomes “ten to fifteen million dollars.” Don't repeat the dollar sign – **that** makes it look like “ten dollars to fifteen million dollars,”

Comment: Thanks, Bradd. I think we could also do this: "a $10–15,000 a year job." This would match your last exemplar with "$10–15 million." Do you agree that "$10–15,000 a year job" (without recasting) looks OK? Thank you.

Comment: That said, Bradd, I think you may concur that these revised versions are spot on (no recast, please): **•It was a $10–15 million a year industry. •The percentages represented a $40-45,000 a year increase in sales.** I've deleted the 2nd $ sign. Do both revised examples look better now? Thanks.

Comment: And would the same apply to a percentage range? **"There was a 10–15% a year increase in funding."** I've omitted the % sign after "10." I think this works, too. Agreed? Again, please no recasts. Thank you.

Comment: •"$1-2 a day surcharge" "a $4–5 pair of shoes" These correct, too? No recast, please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by “no recasts,” but all of those seem reasonable to me. For example, $40–45,000 works because you usually say “forty to forty-five thousand dollars” for a figure like that.